# Reading from Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have used following code to read one column from a CSV file

```
data = pd.read_csv("filename",usecols=[6], header=None ,delimiter=' ')
```

and then

```
for index, row in data.iterrows():
print index ,row
```

It printed the whole information.

> 10024 6    140720848950920 
> Name: 10024, dtype: int64

I just want the value

> 140720848950920

what i need to do

Comment: Do you want `data.iat[0, -1]`?

Answer (score 1):

```
for index, row in data.iterrows():
    print index ,row[6]
```

It seems that it read the whole file

Answer (score 0):

You can create `Series` by parameter `squeeze=True`:

```
s= pd.read_csv("filename",usecols=[6], header=None , sep='\s+', squeeze=True)
```

And then loop:

```
for index, row in s.items():
    print index ,row
```

Or select first value of one column `DataFrame`:

```
data = pd.read_csv("filename",usecols=[6], header=None , sep='\s+')

for index, row in data.iterrows():
   print index ,row[0]
```

**Sample**:

```
import pandas as pd

temp=u"""aa ss dd
fff ff gg
rr t t
y er u"""
#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
data = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), sep='\s+', usecols=[2])
print (data) 
   dd
0  gg
1   t
2   u
```

---

```
for index, row in data.iterrows():
    print (index)
    print ('---')
    print (row[0])
    print (row.iat[0])
    print (row.iloc[0])

0
---
gg
gg
gg
1
---
t
t
t
2
---
u
u
u
```

For comparing 2 columns and filter same rows use:

```
import pandas as pd

temp=u"""A B C
fff ff gg
rr t t
y er u"""
#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
data = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), sep='\s+')
print (data) 
     A   B   C
0  fff  ff  gg
1   rr   t   t
2    y  er   u

data = data[data['B'] == data['C']]
print (data)
    A  B  C
1  rr  t  t
```

Comment: @DileeshDil - For me it working nice, but added alternatives with `iloc` or `iat`, please check edited answer.

Comment: @DileeshDil - Maybe also problem with separator `sep='\s+'`, but hard to know without data.

Comment: actually iwant to compare values in two rows .just printing is not my intention. like current item and next()

Comment: @DileeshDil - I edit answer, what need exactly as output? the best in pandas is avoid loops, so add vectorized non loop solution, which is really fast